# GCC maybe-uninitialized warning - false positive?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

I’ve spent a day trying to debug a `maybe-uninitialized` warning in GCC 12.2. I’ve finally reduced the code to a minimal reproducible example that suggests that the warning is a false positive.

The program bellow allocates memory for four “buckets”, each storing an integer flag and a char pointer, which are to be accessed via pointer arithmetic. It then sets the integer flag in each bucket to `0`. It then infinitely loops over each bucket and prints the (hypothetical) string pointed to by the char pointer only if the flag is `1`. Since all flags were set to `0`, nothing is ever printed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// Diagram of layout of one bucket
// +---------+-----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+
// |   int   | padding to alignof( char* ) |  char*  | padding to alignof( max_align_t ) |
// +---------+-----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+

// Macros to describe layout
#define ROUND_UP( num, multiple ) ( ( ( num + multiple - 1 ) / multiple ) * multiple )
#define CHAR_PTR_OFFSET ROUND_UP( sizeof( int ), alignof( char* ) )
#define BUCKET_SIZE ROUND_UP( CHAR_PTR_OFFSET + sizeof( char* ), alignof( max_align_t ) )

int main( void )
{
  // Allocate memory for four buckets
  char *data = malloc( BUCKET_SIZE * 4 );
  if( !data )
    return 1;
  
  // Set the int in each bucket to 0
  for( size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    *( int* )( data + BUCKET_SIZE * i ) = 0;
  
  // Loop over all four buckets infinitely,
  // dereferencing the char pointer in each one ONLY IF the integer is not zero (i.e. never)
  for( size_t i = 0; ; i = ( i + 1 ) % 4 )
    if( *( int* )( data + BUCKET_SIZE * i ) == 1 )
      puts( *( char** )( data + BUCKET_SIZE * i + CHAR_PTR_OFFSET ) );
  
  return 0;
}
```

GCC with `-std=c11 -O3 -pedantic -Wall` [generates](https://godbolt.org/z/zGT1W5Wvj) the following warning:

```
31:7: warning: '*data_17 + _6' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
31 |       puts( *( char** )( data + BUCKET_SIZE * i + CHAR_PTR_OFFSET ) );
```

If I replace `for( size_t i = 0; ; i = ( i + 1 ) % 4 )` with `for( size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i )`, the warning goes away. It seems that when the loop is infinite (or, in my actual project, aborted by some condition not related to `i`), GCC fails to detect that `*( int* )( data + BUCKET_SIZE * i ) == 1` will always evaluate to false and therefore no char pointer is ever accessed or dereferenced.

Am I right that GCC is generating a false positive here, or am I missing something?

Comment: See whether GCC bug [106757](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106757) seems relevant.  It also features a loop and GCC 12.x claiming out-of-bounds access.